# AppEngine Flex custom readiness & liveness endpoints not firing

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I have configured custom readiness & liveness probe endpoints as described on this page for my AppEngine Flex app:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml

However, looking at the logs, it is clear that it is ignoring my settings which look like the following:

```
liveness_check:
  path: "/liveness_check_custom"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 4
  success_threshold: 2

readiness_check:
  path: "/readiness_check_custom"
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
```

I have a custom log message behind these endpoints which aren't appearing in the logs, and also looking at the nginx.health_check logs I see that it's still hitting the "liveness_check" and "readiness_check" endpoints and not my custom endpoints.

If I hit my endpoints directly myself I see my log messages. Is this Google documentation incorrect or am I missing something? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. Nginx rewrites the the liveness_check and readiness_check to the customized path provided in the app.yaml file when logging the health checks and that's why in the logs you will see the default '/readiness_check' and '/liveness_check' in the nginx logs.

[App Engine creates redundant copies of each health checker](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_check_frequency), and in case a health checker fails, the redundant copy take over with no delay.

Tthe **nginx.health_check** logs for your application are showing logs for the redundant health checkers. They are created automatically by App Engine and they cannot be configured.

The custom health checks logs can be found under **health_logs** in Logging for Google App Engine Application.

There was already a [Public Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/139093675) created for this issue where it explains the previous information about the health checks in App Engine.

Comment: But in the documentation link in my post, for 'path' it says the following which suggests it should be forwarded the call to an endpoint running in my application.
`If you want liveness checks to be forwarded to your application container, specify a URL path, such as "/liveness_check"`

Comment: So are you saying it is NOT possible to have the health checker hit an endpoint inside my actual application to warm up my app? If that's the case then I don't understand what the purpose of the "path" value is that I can override. I'm just trying to warm up my application after the initial deployment since the first call is taking a while to response for a given instance which is not acceptable. And it doesn't appear that AppEngine Flex has a way to warm up (whereas GAE Standard does have the feature unfortunately). Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: In App Engine Standard, warmup requests essentially load your code into a new instance before any live requests reach that instance. To warmup your app in App Engine Flexible, you have to use `initial_delay_sec` setting for [liveness checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#liveness_checks) in your app.yaml file. You have to set up its value to give enough time for your code to initialize, and like this the first coming request to the instance will be processed quickly by your already-initialized code.

Comment: The default value of initial_delay_sec is 300 seconds according to the docs. My app certainly doesn't take 300 seconds to warm up so I don't follow what the solution is supposed to be for Flex. No matter what the readiness & liveness checks are not hitting my app's custom endpoint until I myself make a call manually to it in which time it clearly was the first time my internal app is actually being hit which the logs also confirm. I feel like we're talking about two different things here. Anyway thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

the **liveness_check** and **readiness_check** sections defined in **app.yaml** is the new method for health checks in app engine flex. **liveness_check** signals that VM and the Docker container are running, and **readiness_check** signals that an instance can accept incoming requests.

you can customize a specific path to reach your application. However, nginx rewrites the paths '/readiness_check' and '/liveness_check' to custom-specified paths when sending requests to the application within the VM. You will therefore see '/readiness_check' and '/liveness_check' in the nginx logs.

That's aside, if you want to apply warming up on your App Engine, you have to use **initial_delay_sec** setting in your liveness_check section. The default is 300 but you can change that to what you believe is enough for your app to accept request (you can put it between 0-3600 seconds)