# AppEngine Flex custom liveness_check path not reaching app endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I've configured a custom liveness_check in my app.yaml. I've confirmed that the endpoint exists, and when I call it directly I receive a 200 response. However, when GoogleHC calls it it receives a 500 response and fails. My best guess is that the health check is not routing into the application itself. Is this supposed to work?

An image of my logs showing my successful call to /liveness_check followed by the unsuccessful call by GoogleHC:
[image]

And here is the relevant part of my app.yaml:

```
liveness_check:
  path: "/liveness_check"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 4
  success_threshold: 2
  initial_delay_sec: 300
```

I've checked that GoogleHC IP address is not blocked by appengine firewall.

This looks like a related question:
[AppEngine Flex custom readiness & liveness endpoints not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066328/appengine-flex-custom-readiness-liveness-endpoints-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the Liveness checks timeout is set to 4 seconds in the `app.yaml` file. Please take note of this as liveness probes typically take longer than the default timeout of 4 seconds. Also, the warning messages you are receiving provide you the opportunity to alert that an instance is unhealthy within the designated timeout period.

Please be aware that the App Engine regularly sends health check queries to make sure that an instance is operational and that it is fully deployed and prepared to respond to incoming requests. For more details, please see the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/how-instances-are-managed#health_checking).

As a result, I kindly ask that you try raising the `initial-delay-sec` parameter values in [liveness checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/reference/app-yaml?tab=custom#liveness_checks).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sandeep. I increased the initial-delay-sec to 600 seconds and I still see the same error. I also don't think that would address the root problem that I am able to curl the /liveness_check endpoint and receive a 200 response while GoogleHC receives a 500 error. Do you have any thoughts on what could cause this?

Comment: Maybe you can check with liveness_check path, If you want to use the default liveness_check then make sure you need to remove the path.

Comment: I do not want to use the default path, I want to use a custom path. The custom path returns a 200 response when I call it, but when the auto liveness check calls it it receives a 500 error. this is well after startup, so timeout for initial-delay-sec is not the cause. So I'm looking for advice on what could cause this behavior

Comment: It seems like it requires a project inspection to find the cause of the error. Try to contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)